# skipping if condition if database value is empty

Tags: php

I'm working on getting values from the database and convert it into json object. It is working fine, but the problem is if the value is blank(Not assigned 'null' value), it is showing null in json output. I tried if condition to check for it and skip it if the value is blank. But it is not working. what can I do for if condition so that if the value is blank it should skip that one. Please suggestion some solution to it. I'm a newbie to php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","plinlt","lajisdfla");

mysql_select_db("plinlt");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT field_id_6 FROM exp_channel_data") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["events"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
       if($row["field_id_6"]==null)
       {
        Echo "";
       }
       else
       {
       $product["event"] = $row["field_id_6"];
        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["events"], $product);
       }
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $preserved = array_reverse($response, true);

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($preserved);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Blank values are not the same as NULL (unless you're on Horribacle).

Comment: use if(empty($row["field_id_6"])){}

Answer (score 2):

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

[PHP Manual: continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

To check for an empty variable, the better option is usually `empty()`
[PHP Manual: empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

So, you can use something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $product = array();

   // if the field is blank, skip this row
   if( empty($row["field_id_6"]) )
      continue;

   // it's not blank, do what we need
   $product["event"] = $row["field_id_6"];
   array_push($response["events"], $product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in if condition,

```
if($row["field_id_6"]==null || $row["field_id_6"] == "" || $row["field_id_6"] == " ")
{
  //your code
}
```

Comment: If you are not quite sure about the fetched result then you can use if(isset($row["field_id_6"])) before your operations..

Comment: I tried you code. But it is showing following result. {"success":1,"events":[{"event":null},{"event":"Bro. N Bulkley preaching in AM Service"},{"event":null},{"event":null}]}. What can I add into if condition so that it skip that iteration.

Comment: continue; will help you.. continue statement will skip the further computation and continues the loop ! more details here. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) for this. It checks whether a variable is NULL. Also [isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Examples could be found on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if($row["field_id_6"]==null)
{
   Echo "";
}
```

try

```
if($row["field_id_6"]==null || $row["field_id_6"]=="null" || empty($row["field_id_6"]) || trim($row["field_id_6"])=="")
{
   continue;
}
```

Comment: I tried you code. But still showing like this {"success":1,"events":[{"event":null},{"event":"Bro. N Bulkley preaching in AM Service"},{"event":null},{"event":null}]}. Not skipping that iteration.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was bit busy somewhere else. 
I have edited the code. Can you please try and let me know if its working or not.